# Python: Sorting the list alphabetically ignoring vowels

Tags: python, list, sorting

Please gently with me as I am beginner. I read the answer for Sorting list of string alphabetically ignoring vowels. But I don't really understand how it sorts in this method:

```
l = ['alpha', 'beta']
vowels = ['aeiouAEIOU']
sorted(l, key=lambda s: ''.join(c for c in s if c not in vowels))
```

My questions:

1. how can the sort can loop at the character level rather than word without splitting words?
2. If c not vowel then join letters back to word then how they sort the words with having vowels? what happens to the other words with vowels?

Comment: There is no such thing as "sorting at the word level". Words are always sorted character by character (what's the alternative?). Your second question is not clear.

Comment: Just change your vowels to `vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'`. Right now you are asking if one of the letters is equal to the sublist.

Comment: All right! I got it now. What lambda does is eliminating the vowels appearing in a word then pass the left over string back for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the strings in your list as if they do not have vowels.  So, `hello` should sort as `hll` and `world` should sort as `wrld`.  You may try removing vowels in your sorting lambda:

```py
l = ['help', 'hello', 'world', 'weld']
l = sorted(l, key=lambda s: re.sub(r'[AEIOUaeiou]', '', s))
print(l)  # ['hello', 'help', 'weld', 'world']
```

Comment: what is re.sub(r'[AEIOUaeiou]' means?

Comment: it means substitute the vowels (lower and upper case) with a blank ''.